# List of Guids not Model Binding Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, aurelia

i'm sending an array of Guids to an ASP.NET Core Web app using aurelia-fetch-client, however on the server side the model binder doesn't pick it up and the list of `notificationIds` is `null`. However when i make the request through Swagger, or CURL it binds just fine.

I changed the signature of my controller method to accept a list of strings just in case there was something wrong with the GUID formatting, but same issue.

JS

```
var body = {notificationIds :  this.notifications.map(x => x.notificationId) };
    console.log("Dismissing All notifications");

    await this.httpClient.fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/notifications/clear',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: json(body),
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With': 'Fetch'
            },
            mode: 'cors'
        }).then(response => {
            if(response.status == 204){
               //Success! Remove Notifications from VM
            }
            else{

                console.log(response.status)
            }
        })
```

Controller Method

```
// POST: api/Notifications
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("clear")]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent)]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]List<string> notificationIds)
        {
            if (notificationIds.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                return BadRequest("No notifications requested to be cleared");
            }

            var name = User.Claims.ElementAt(1);

            await _notificationRepository.Acknowledge(notificationIds, name.Value);

            return NoContent();
}
```

Interesting thing is that Chrome (V62) shows nothing posted.
[image]

But Fiddler does

[image]

Comment: You aren't setting the returned data to any properties on your VM from what I can see.

Comment: I don't want to set anything on the VM. It's the the fact that when i post a list of guids, the model binder on the server doesn't pick them up that's the problem

Comment: Ah. I completely misread the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem....:)

Comment: See that's the interesting thing. Chrome shows nothing posted, but fiddler does....

Comment: @peinearydevelopment yes, that's it. Christ i'm an idiot sometimes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of the object you are passing from JavaScript isn't the same shape of an object you are telling the ASP.NET framework to expect.

There are two ways that you could fix this issue:

**Option 1:**
In your JavaScript, change your body to `var body = this.notifications.map(x => x.notificationId);`

**Option 2:**
Create an object in c# that reflects what you are passing from your JavaScript.

```
namespace Foo
{
  public class Bar
  {
    public List<string> NotificationIds { get; set; }
  }
}
```

and then update your controller method to the following:

```
// POST: api/Notifications
[HttpPost]
[Route("clear")]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent)]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Bar bar)
{
  if (bar.NotificationIds.IsNullOrEmpty())
  {
    return BadRequest("No notifications requested to be cleared");
  }

  var name = User.Claims.ElementAt(1);
  await _notificationRepository.Acknowledge(bar.NotificationIds, name.Value);
  return NoContent();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're not sending a list of GUIDs you are sending an object with a property that contains a list of GUIDs.  Either create and use a view model (as described by peinearydevelopment) or accept a `dynamic` parameter that refers to the json object.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] dynamic json)
{
    var notificationIds = json.notifcationIds;
    ...
```